# How to implement own DataType property for UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, properties

I would like to implement a usercontrol which gets a enumtype via XAML code. Now is the question how do I implement a property which can receive a DataType. What I've tried so far is the following:

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Test : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       #region DependencyProperty: EnumType
        public Type EnumType
        {
            get
            {
                return (Type)GetValue(EnumTypeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EnumTypeProperty, value);                
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EnumType", typeof(Type), typeof(Test),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
        #endregion
}
```

And in XAML I tried this:

...

```
<Grid>
        <local:Test EnumType="{x:Type local:TestEnum}" />
</Grid>
```

...

The TestEnum:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    eins,
    zwei,
    drei
}
```

But that does not work. It seems that the EnumType property is never set.

Has anyone any idea on how to do that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public static DependencyProperty EnumValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EnumValue", typeof(TestEnum), typeof(Test), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public TestEnum EnumValue
    {
        get { return (TestEnum)GetValue(EnumValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnumValueProperty, value); }
    }

<local:Test EnumValue="eins"/>
```

I'm not sure why you were using Type as your property type, just use the TestEnum Type.

Do you get any build errors? I often find that sometimes intellisense fails in the XAML editor until I've built the control again, can be a red herring.

**EDIT**

Apologies, I got the complete wrong end of the stick, I managed to get your code to compile and run, however I don't get to see the enum type as a valid type in intellisense.

Comment: Presumably TestEnum is just an example. The EnumType property should be settable to be any type.

Comment: I meant the data type of the property is "Type", not the enum type:
public *Type* EnumType

Comment: @bobsmith833, sorry, I wasn't reading the question correctly at all.

Comment: That's OK! This is a slightly unusual thing to be doing so I didn't interpret the question correctly at first either...

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think it is not working? I tried your code above, adding a PropertyChangedCallback:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnumType", typeof(Type), typeof(Test),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MyCallBack));

    private static void MyCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // See if we reach this point
    }
```

And it seems to be called as expected, assigning the Type value to TestEnum as you require.

Comment: Ooh I see - I did just look in the wrong place for the property to change! Thank you guys alot for all your answers - helped me out again!
Thumbs up!